# Stopping bubbling event in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, events, touch, preventdefault

I'm trying to handle touch/mouse events. So, I created this code:

```
myObject.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault(); 
    console.log("Touched"); 
    mouseTouchDown(e);
}); 
myObject.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
    console.log("Clicked"); 
    mouseTouchDown(e);
}); 
function mouseTouchDown(e){
console.log("Some function.");};
```

I want to stop bubbling of touch event, so click won't be fired afterwards. It works on Chrome, but on Firefox I get in console:

```
Touched
Clicked
```

How can I stop mouse click firing after touch event?

I tried returning false, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Whilst this looks like a FF bug, are you working in a situation where the action of a touch should actually be different to the action of a click? If it's not time sensitive to below 300ms you could just perform the method on click events instead of both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have u attached both events with same element?

If that is the case the error is not because of bubbling happening.while mouse click several events will happen like `mousedown`, `touchstart` ..etc.so if you want to avoid mouse click event occuring add `preventDefault()` in the mouse down.This will disable default mouse click event happening on that element.

Comment: I need to handle cases: element

Comment: @user3629015 can u be more specific on cases?

Comment: I need to handle cases: 1.) element will be clicked with mouse on pc. 2.) element will be touched on any touch device. That's why I attached 2 events, for mouse and for touch. Everything works fine for simple mouse click, but touch event also triggers mouse click. So according to this article http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/ I added  e.preventDefault(); It works nicely in Chrome, but unfortunately not in FF. Got me a little bit confused.

Comment: it will work like a charm.

myObject.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e){
 window.touched = true;
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault(); 
    console.log("Touched"); 
    mouseTouchDown(e);
}); 
myObject.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
 if ( !window.touched ) { 
  console.log("Clicked"); 
  mouseTouchDown(e);
 }
 window.touched = false;
});

Comment: hope this answer helped

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in the browser, your code looks fine.

See: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=977226.
What OS/version of Firefox are you testing this with?

Comment: Wait, so manipulating a _touch event_ affects the similar _click event_?

Comment: @PaulS. You can prevent a click event from being triggered by that touch event, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events#Tracking_new_touches

Comment: Awesome, but it looks like it's [specifically `.preventDefault` on the initial event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events#Additional_tips) which is breaking the chain of "the default action is to fire a click event". I didn't realise these were chained before; thought the one action caused the two to happen independently

Comment: I'm using emulation on FF 43.0.1